# Show that the range of the function $z(t)=t^3+it^6$, $-1\leq t\leq 1$, is a smooth curve even though the given parametrization is not admissible.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, parametric

This is problem **4.1.4** from "Fundamentals of Complex Analysis: with Applications to Engineering and Science".

**Problem:**

Show that the range of the function $z(t)=t^3+it^6$, $-1\leq t\leq 1$, is a smooth curve even though the given parametrization is not admissible.

---

There is clearly something I don't understand, since I think that the curve is **not** smooth. You can find the definition of a smooth curve at the bottom of this post. The condition I can't get my head around is the second one. It says, in my case, $z'(t)$ never vanishes on $[-1,1]$. $z'(t)$ is given by the vector

$$z'(t)=(dx/dt,dy/dt)=(3t^2,6t^5)=3t^2+6t^5i.$$

That it vanishes means that $z'(t)=0$. Hence 
$$3t^2+6t^5i=0\iff 3t^2=0\land 6t^5=0.$$

The above is true when $t=0$, which is in the specified interval above. So it is not smooth.

I know my conclusion is false since I should prove that the curve is smooth. But I don't get why my reasoning is wrong. :(

---

**Definition:**

A point set $\gamma$ in the complex plane is said to be a **smooth arc** if it is the range of some continuous complex-valued function $z=z(t)$, $a\leq t\leq b$, that satisfies the following conditions:

($i$) $z(t)$ has a continuous derivative on $[a,b]$,

($ii$) $z'(t)$ never vanishes on $[a,b]$,

($iii$) z(t) is one-to-one on $[a,b]$.

A point set $\gamma$ is called a **smooth closed curve** if it is the range of some continuous function $z=z(t)$, $a\leq t\leq b$, satisfying conditions $(i)$ and $(ii)$ and the following:

$(iii)'$ $z(t)$ is one-to-one on the half-open interval $[a,b)$, but $z(b)=z(a)$ and $z'(b)=z'(a)$.

That "$\gamma$" is a smooth curve" means that $\gamma$ is either a smooth arc or a smooth closed curve.

---

Thanks for your time! :)

Comment: Your curve is also given by the function $u\in [-1,1] \to u+i u^2$, and it is smooth.

Comment: Oh yeah, right. Thank you. I feel pretty stupid now. I get it. :)

Comment: $y=x^2$ is smooth, since this is differentiable.